# unable to display enumarion fields and input field in orchard using placment.info for custom form

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am using the custom form module in or chard and I am getting an issue to where if I am an anonymous user I can't view my custom form when I alter the placements of my elements using placement.info here is my code for the placment.info

I have all the correct permissions for the form so anonymous users can see the form until i try to alter the placement of content.

```
 <Match ContentType="myform">
<Place Fields_Input_Edit-BandName="RightColumn:0.1"/>
<Place Fields_Input_Edit-FacebookLink="RightColumn:1"/>
<Place Fields_Enumeration_Edit="LeftColumn:0.2"/>
```

and here is the zone layout that i have inside of alternate

```
    <div class="edit-item">
    <div class="edit-item-primary">
        @if (Model.Content != null)
        {
            <div class="edit-item-content">
                <div class="first-zone">
                    @Zone(Model.CafeCompetitionLocation)
                </div>
                <div class="second-zone">
                    @Zone(Model.YourName)
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

for some reason this works when authenticated but not when you're not logged in please help. and explain to me if i am doing something wrong the main goal here is to be able to style a form quickly and the correct way

Comment: I don't see any zones called 'RightColum' or 'LeftColumn'?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to allow anonymous access to your form in Permissions

[custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-and-anonymous-users-permission](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-and-anonymous-users-permission)

Just remembered this post as i was typing.

Comment: I already have all the correct permissions. It just doesn't show only when you add an numeration field

Comment: uuuum, interesting. let me have a look at the field... are you really using 1.8, 1.8.1 or 1.9+? as 1.9 might have a different implementation if you used the new Layouts Module